# JPA Query with multiple entity using union

Tags: mysql, spring, entity, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I wrote a query in JpaRepository to get list of all bills which is created by current user and also under subordinates of current user. I tried with below code.It did not show any error but return empty.I used mysql

```
public interface BillRepository extends JpaRepository<Bill, Long>{
@Query("select b from Bill b where b.createdBy = ?1 union select bb from Bill bb where bb.createdBy in (select r from Resource r where r.reportingManager = ?1)")
    Page<Bill> findAllByPage(Long id,Pageable page);
}
```

Please give a solution.Thanks in advance

Comment: UNION is not valid JPQL syntax

Comment: can you help me to write the above query in correct format ? thanks in advance.@Neil Stockton

Comment: I think your query could be done with the conditional operator `and`,. The query would be: `select distinct  b from Bill b where b.createdBy = ?1 and where b.createdBy in (select r from Resource r where r.reportingManager = ?1)`. Try it.